# Kernel Code : where can I find and how to debug the kernel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, ubuntu-12.04, linux-device-driver

Recently I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ISO image in my desktop. Below is the output of the kernel version I have installed:

```
# uname -r
3.5.0-41-generic
```

I am trying to develop a VFS and want the kernel source code version '3.5.0-41-generic' for reference purpose - where can I find the same?

What are the excellent kernel debugging options looking at logs and mapping them to kernel code?

How and which debugger I can use to debug a live kernel flow execution?

Are there ways I can add more printk methods and re-modify the modules? Say I want to know how a FS mount method works - I can modify the required FS code (adding more printk functions) re-compile and reload the modules. Now with aid of my new printk functions I can understand the flow

Comment: You might want to consider using [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/) instead of working in the kernel.

Comment: Well the objective is to learn and code a VFS so we need to write all the modules

Comment: i don't use ubuntu but i think you can install the kernel source with apt-get on ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you install vanilla 3.5 kernel and try to develop on it?
As a kernel debugger you can use kGDB or just printk.

But... I suggest you to test your vfs on linux running on qemu. Qemu is able to debug the running linux - so you can connect gdb to it and debug the whole emulating system.

Comment: Can you please explain more about vanilla kernel - is it that code written in vanilla kernel easy and be ported to all other Linux OS like RHEL, UBUNTU etc?

Comment: As a vanilla kernel I mean the kernel downloaded from kernel.org. It is clean kernel without any additional patches. It should work on any Linux distribution.